# Why does Automapper map Driver.Name to DriverName automatically

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class ScheduledDeduction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public partial class Driver
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
```

and View Model class:

```
public abstract class ScheduledDeductionDetailVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Driver Name")]
    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following rule of Automapper:

```
CreateMap<Infrastructure.Asset.ScheduledDeduction, ViewModels.ScheduledDeductionDetailVM>();
```

and try to use:

```
ScheduledDeduction scheduledDeduction = db.ScheduledDeductions.Find(id);
ScheduledDeductionDetailVM model = mapper.Map<ScheduledDeductionDetailVM>(scheduledDeduction);
```

and it works! Why? ScheduledDeductionDetailVM has property DriverName , which can be got from ScheduledDeduction.Driver.Name and it never described at all. But it's mapped correctly...

Comment: Haven't you defined any mapping rules?

Comment: That is too broad a question. That is how the framework was designed. It is mentioned in documentation. It is called [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening)

Comment: I refere to the configuration that is presented here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration? Haven't you done anything similar to the things described there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper uses many different [conventions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conventions), and this behaviour is also part of different conventions. On the page about [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) it is stated that

> If for any property on the destination type a property, method, or a
>   method prefixed with "Get" does not exist on the source type,
>   AutoMapper splits the destination member name into individual words
>   (by PascalCase conventions).

But if you do this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();                
    cfg.CreateMap<ScheduledDeduction, ScheduledDeductionDetailVM>();
});
```

It will no longer be the case, because you changed destination member naming convention from PascalCase to LowerUnderscore.

Or if you do this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    var profile = (Profile)cfg;
    profile.DefaultMemberConfig.MemberMappers.Clear();
    cfg.CreateMap<ScheduledDeduction, ScheduledDeductionDetailVM>();
});
```

It will also break behaviour you observe, because you removed member naming conventions.

Answer (score 4):

That is a feature of the framework.

According to [documentation about Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening)

> One of the common usages of object-object mapping is to take a complex
>   object model and flatten it to a simpler model.
>
> ....
>
> When you configure a source/destination type pair in AutoMapper, the
>   configurator attempts to match properties and methods on the source
>   type to properties on the destination type. If for any property on the
>   destination type a property, method, or a method prefixed with "Get"
>   does not exist on the source type, AutoMapper splits the destination
>   member name into individual words (by PascalCase conventions).